# Adding Users to Report Server Users Table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to add users to the Report Servers dbo.Users Table. I see a 36 character USERID. Does anyone know how this is generated? How do i get users to show up in this table?

Answer (score -1):

I do not think you should directly modify/add data in ReportServer database.

To add a new user, go to your Report Manager web page.
For a default installation, it is http://[computer-name]/Reports
For a named instance suppose the instance is sql01, it is http://[computer-name]/Reports_sql01

Next, click on Properties tab. In Security, choose New Role Assignment.
There you can add users that exist on your Local machine, or on your company domain.
This user will show up in the Users table. But again, SQL Documentation advises not to directly manipulate data there. Good luck!